# Click a <tr> tag object with only a class, autoit

Tags: html, html-table, autoit

I am trying to click a tr tag object with Autoit

Everything I tried failed..

```
<tr class="auctionItemRow evenRow" itemGroup="extra"
itemKey="item_hour_13" onclick="Auction.showItem(this)">
```

but I can't find the solution...

Here is more code from the website:

```
    <div id="auction_container">
        <div id="auction_headline">
            AUKTIONSHAUS
        </div>

        <div id="auction_filter_wrapper" class="filter_wrapper">
            <div id="auction_filter_selector" class="filter_selector">Filter</div>
            <div id="auction_filter_selection" class="filter_selection">
                <div class="filter_item" id="filter_all">Alle</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_battery">Batterien</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_rocket">Raketen und Minen</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_generator">Generatoren</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_extra">Extras</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_weapon">Waffen</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_special">Spezial</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_ship">Schiffe</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_booster">Booster</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_shipdesign">Schiffdesigns</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="filter_module">Module</div>
                            <div class="auction_filter_btm"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="auction_history_dropdown" class="filter_wrapper">
            <div id="auction_history_selector" class="filter_selector">Auktion wählen</div>
                    <div id="auction_history_selection_hour" class="filter_selection">
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12455">2015-07-06 12:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12454">2015-07-06 11:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12453">2015-07-06 10:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12452">2015-07-06 09:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12451">2015-07-06 08:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12450">2015-07-06 07:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12449">2015-07-06 06:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12448">2015-07-06 05:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12447">2015-07-06 04:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12446">2015-07-06 03:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12445">2015-07-06 02:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12444">2015-07-06 01:10:00</div>
                            <div class="auction_filter_btm"></div>
            </div>
                    <div id="auction_history_selection_day" class="filter_selection">
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12417">2015-07-05 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12392">2015-07-04 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12367">2015-07-03 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12342">2015-07-02 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12317">2015-07-01 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12292">2015-06-30 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12266">2015-06-29 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12241">2015-06-28 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12216">2015-06-27 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12191">2015-06-26 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12166">2015-06-25 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12141">2015-06-24 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="auction_filter_btm"></div>
            </div>
                    <div id="auction_history_selection_week" class="filter_selection">
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12267">2015-06-29 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_12091">2015-06-22 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_11915">2015-06-15 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_11739">2015-06-08 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_11562">2015-06-01 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_11386">2015-05-25 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_11209">2015-05-18 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_11033">2015-05-11 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_10857">2015-05-04 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_10681">2015-04-27 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_10504">2015-04-20 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="filter_item" id="history_10328">2015-04-13 00:10:00</div>
                            <div class="auction_filter_btm"></div>
            </div>
                </div>

        <div id="auction_tab_wrapper">
            <div class="auction_tab_main auction_tab_active" id="tab_hour">STÜNDLICH</div>
            <div class="auction_tab_main" id="tab_day">TÄGLICH</div>
            <div class="auction_tab_main" id="tab_week">WÖCHENTLICH</div>
        </div>

        <div id="auction_content" class="auction_deco_1">
            <div id="auction_top_area">
                <div class="auction_subtab auction_subtab_active" id="auction_current">
                    AUKTION
                </div>
                <div class="auction_subtab" id="auction_mybids">
                    MEINE GEBOTE
                </div>
                <div class="auction_subtab" id="auction_history">
                    CHRONIK
                </div>

                <div id="auction_countdown">
                    Auktion endet in
                    <span id="countdown_hour" class="countdown_item">00:00</span>
                    <span id="countdown_day" class="countdown_item">00:00:00</span>
                    <span id="countdown_week" class="countdown_item">00:00:00:00</span>
                </div>
            </div>

                    <div id="auction_content_hour" class="auction_content_sub">
                <div class="auctionList auction_list_current">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="auctionItemList">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="auction_item_name" colspan="2">Item-Name</th>
                            <th class="auction_item_type">Typ</th>
                            <th class="auction_item_highest">Höchstbietender</th>
                            <th class="auction_item_current">Gebot</th>
                            <th class="auction_item_you">Dein Gebot</th>
                            <th class="auction_item_instant">Sofortkauf</th>
                        </tr>

                    <tbody class="auction_item_wrapper">

<tr class="auctionItemRow evenRow" itemGroup="extra" itemKey="item_hour_13" onclick="Auction.showItem(this)">
                            <td class="firstColumn">
                                <img src="http://darkorbit-22.ah.bpcdn.net/do_img/global/items/equipment/extra/cpu/sle-04_30x30.png?__cv=1a05e234c920672ee54f9c303e9df300" width="30" height="30" alt="Slot-CPU 4" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="auction_item_name_col">
                                Slot-CPU 4
                            </td>
                            <td class="auction_item_type">
                                Extras
                            </td>
                            <td class="auction_item_highest" showUser="5wrCw" title="*SO* - Klicke für Details">

                                *SO*
                            </td>
                            <td class="auction_item_current">
                                10.000
                            </td>
                            <td class="auction_item_you">
                                0
                            </td>
                            <td class="auction_item_instant">
                                                                    250.000

                                <input type="hidden" id="item_hour_13_image" value="http://darkorbit-22.ah.bpcdn.net/do_img/global/items/equipment/extra/cpu/sle-04_63x63.png?__cv=33d7086513c36d8f5d70660993f70800" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="item_hour_13_descr" value="Gibt 10 neue Slots für Extras im Schiff frei." />
                                <input type="hidden" id="item_hour_13_bid" value="10000" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="item_hour_13_buyPrice" value="250000" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="item_hour_13_lootId" value="equipment_extra_cpu_sle-04" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="item_hour_13_instantBuy" value="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

            <div id="auction_item_info">
                <div id="item_info_image_wrapper">
                    <img src="" width="63" height="63" id="auction_item_image" />
                </div>

                <div id="auction_item_descr" class="item_qtip" title=""></div>
                <div id="auction_descr_ttip"></div>

                <div id="auction_item_buy">
                    <form method="post" name="placeBid" action="/indexInternal.es?action=internalAuction&reloadToken=072a0522929ba9c183f8eb4652357b32" onsubmit="return Auction.checkForm()"><input type="hidden" name="reloadToken" value="072a0522929ba9c183f8eb4652357b32">
                        <input type="hidden" name="auctionType" value="hour" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="subAction" value="bid" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="lootId" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="" />

                        <input type="text" name="credits" value="0" />
                        <img src="http://darkorbit-22.ah.bpcdn.net/do_img/global/auction/credits.png?__cv=505a650ada9ece3b973a30abc53c8500" width="21" height="21" class="currency_icon" id="auction_crd" />

                        <input type="submit" name="auction_buy_button" class="disabled" id="auction_place_bid" value="BIETEN" />
                        <img src="http://darkorbit-22.ah.bpcdn.net/do_img/global/auction/uridium.png?__cv=b78e7600ee1cbc03b3f7062390a87600" width="21" height="21" class="currency_icon" id="auction_uri" />
                    </form>

                    <input type="text" name="instant" readonly="readonly" value="0" />
                    <input type="button" class="auction_buy_button disabled" id="auction_instant_buy" value="SOFORTKAUF" onclick="Auction.instantBuy()" />
                </div>
            </div>

                    </div>
        <div class="mail_wrapper">
                                                    <div id="auction_mail_receive" class="button-singleCheckbox "></div>
            <div id="auction_mail_receiveLabel">Bestätigungsmail</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I think this is the js for it:

http://darkorbit-22.ah.bpcdn.net/js/auction.js?__cv=5522feca4e9b87b8e195f66bc31c3600

Comment: Can you post examples of what you tried so far and where you are failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element (TR) you want to click doesn't have ID or NAME, your best shot is to list all TagNames (TRs) and compare some other attribute.

Example:

```
Local $oTrs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "TR")

For $oTr In $oTrs
    If $oTr.classname == "auctionItemRow evenRow" Then
        $oTr.click
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next
```